# Add 2 sums using + sign and provide sum value with a comma before thousandth unit

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, currency

I use:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY,SUM(CT.CONTRIB_INCL_AMT)) ,1) as char(12)) as TEST
```

which works correctly. However, when try to add another sum using the + sign followed by another exact format SQL statement, it gives a syntax error. The 2 sums when run separately work OK but having a + sign to sum them together results in the error message, 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword as'.

Without the money conversion formatting the + sign works OK, but doesn't work when the money conversion operation is included. Please help.

Comment: could you paste your both SUM query how you are trying to add

Comment: That query does not work correctly. You may have a simpler version of the query that works, but that one throws errors when testing locally.

Comment: SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY,SUM(CT.CONTRIB_INCL_AMT)) ,1) as char(12)) as test
FROM GMCON_CONTRIB CT
where   CT.file_id = :FileId
and  CT.CONTRIB_TYPE_CODE = 'FI' 

+

cast (CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY,SUM(CT2.CONTRIB_INCL_AMT)) ,1) as char(12)) as test
---ISNULL(cast((select SUM(CT2.CONTRIB_INCL_AMT))as char(12)) as amount
FROM GMCON_CONTRIB CT
left join GMCON_CONTRIB CT2 on ct.CONTRIB_ID = ct2.CONTRIB_ID
where   CT.file_id = :FileId
and  CT.CONTRIB_TYPE_CODE = 'FI'
and  CT2.CONTRIB_TYPE_CODE = 'RA'
as test

Comment: Above is the Sum query, it's not working that;s why I ask. It sums OK for multi  values if I use ISNULL (cast(( selectSUM....), but if I want a comma by using cast (..(money..) it gives syntax error the second statements (after +)